# Running a Java Application on a server from my PC

Tags: java

If I have a Java application running on a server that I need to access and run from my PC as a normal user, do I need Java installed on my PC as well? Also do the versions of Java need to be compatible i.e. say Java 8 on both Server and PC ?

Comment: You do not need Java installed on your computer. All your computer is doing is to send commands to the server-computer. The commands are all executed by the server.

Comment: Could you give more details about what the application is and what you will need to do from your PC?

Comment: why do you need java on your pc? Is that to run java applets embedded in websites that you browse onto?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "access and run from my PC". Are you saying you want to create a different instance of the application to run it locally on your PC?

Comment: @sam its just an in house developed Java application, hosted on a server. I'm trying to understand what I need to upgrade as its on Java 5 i.e. do I need to do anything to my PC as well as the server.

Comment: Hi Steve if it's just running on the server and you only need to access it to start it and look at the logs etc. you just need an SSH client, no need for the latest version if java.

Comment: @J woodchuck no, don't need a separate instance of it. just want to run the app which is on the server. I think @gendarme as answered now - there is no need to install java on your pc.

Comment: Since the answer depends on **what the app is actually doing** we can't give **good** answers here. For example, if the app is actually providing a web frontend then no, you do not Java yourself. If the app requires a specific client written in Java or you need to run the app itself, then you *do* need Java. As always: low quality questions yield low quality answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Java application running on a server that I need to access and run from my PC

Is not clear what your Java app does.

- If it's a web application that you can access with a web browser (chrome, firefox etc. ) then no, you don't need Java installed in your computer ( unless this web app serves applets, which I hope is not the case )
- If it's Java app that provides some "service" then you need Java in your PC only if the client of that service needs a Java to run, in that case you just need JRE

> I'm trying to understand what I need to upgrade as it's on Java 5

If you're talking about *developing* the app **in** your PC then yes, definitely you need the Java SDK

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. I have various applications some web applications some not, but in both instances they just need to be used from the PC (not run as such) by a normal user. In your answer , what would an example of a 'service' be? So the reason why people need java installed on their pc in general is to run java applets embedded in web applications?

Answer (score 1):

From your PC, if you are connecting to server to execute the Java application, then you don't need Java installed in your machine. When you log into server, basically you would be using the server resources like CPU, OS, Softwares installed (e.g. Java). In these cases, the PC would just be a dumb terminal.

Answer (score 1):

> If I have a Java application running on a server that I need to access

What do you mean access? Do you want to access it from server (I suppose that is what you are already doing) or you want to deploy it on your local machine and access locally? (Yes that is totally possible)

> do I need Java installed on my PC as well?

If you want to only run, you only need JRE but if you want to develop, you need JDK which has JRE in it as well.

> Also do the versions of Java need to be compatible i.e. say Java 8 on
>   both Server and PC ?

That totally depends, Java8 code is not compatible with Java7 (lambdas, streams) if java8 code is used, then yes you need java8 but if server is using older version and you are using a new version, that will work fine.

Though, I will still recommend to go with same versions (Keep in mind the 32, 64 bit architecture as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can not access to an app if you didn't build a connection module, I mean, If you build a program you have to set up a way to connect, otherwise you will not be able to connect.

If you have installed a program you didn't develop then you need to use another program which works as client, you will need install java if the client program requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Nope the java is not required in the pc unless if you want to test your war file in your pc , the server can manage web application,if you have an engine in server you can create a another web application that can manage the engine without using java application at client side

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it seems you are trying to upgrade the JDK used by your Java application to a newer version. To do that you could bite the bullet and just do the upgrade with your fingers crossed, hoping it works. But this would of course be very risky if it is a "Production" application.

A far better approach would be to get the app running locally by downloading the source and getting a local server instance running on your pc (tomcat, jboss - whatever the app uses on the server itself). Then upgrade the JDK in your local version as a test.

If all goes well, then upgrade on the server in the Production version just as you did locally. But if you run into issues or errors while running locally, debug and fix them so you can apply those same fixes to the Production version on the server before upgrading. Once all is running smoothly locally, you will have some reasonable expectation that it will run smoothly in Production as well (assuming the environments match).